# XSLT | Json-xml conversion | remove few elements from the json array

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Try to convert Json to xml using xslt, the Json is having an array. I want only few elements of that array in my xml file.
But the value of the elements left out elements are also getting added in the xml.

Input Json:

```
{
  "a": "v1",
  "arr": [
    {
      "ar1": "av1",
      "ar2": "av2",
      "ar3": "av3",
      "ar4": "av4",
      "ar5": "av5",
      "ar6": "av6"
    }
  ],
  "b": "v2",
  "c": "v3"
}
```

xslt used for conversion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="jsonText" />
    <xsl:param name="json" select ="parse-json($jsonText)"/>
    <xsl:template name="init">
        <body>
            <envelope>
                <dataset>
                    <AA>{$json?a}</AA>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$json => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json'} ) => json-to-xml()"/>
                </dataset>
            </envelope>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'arr']">
        <xsl:iterate select="*">
            <arr>
                <ar1>{fn:string[@key = 'ar1']}</ar1>
                <ar2>{fn:string[@key = 'ar2']}</ar2>
            </arr>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I got using the above xslt:

```
<body>
    <envelope>
        <dataset>
            <AA>v1</AA>
            <arr>
                <ar1>av1</ar1>
                <ar2>av2</ar2>
            </arr>v1v2v3
        </dataset>
    </envelope>
</body>
```

expected output:

```
<body>
    <envelope>
        <dataset>
            <AA>v1</AA>
            <arr>
                <ar1>av1</ar1>
                <ar2>av2</ar2>
            </arr>
        </dataset>
    </envelope>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems instead of using `<xsl:apply-templates select="$json => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json'} ) => json-to-xml()"/>` you could just use

```
        <arr>
            <ar1>{$json?arr?*?ar1}</ar1>
            <ar2>{$json?arr?*?ar2}</ar2>
        </arr>
```

[Online sample here](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22fn%22%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20omit-xml-declaration%3D%22yes%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22jsonText%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22a%22%3A%20%22v1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22arr%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar1%22%3A%20%22av1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar2%22%3A%20%22av2%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar3%22%3A%20%22av3%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar4%22%3A%20%22av4%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar5%22%3A%20%22av5%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ar6%22%3A%20%22av6%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22b%22%3A%20%22v2%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22c%22%3A%20%22v3%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22json%22%20select%3D%22parse-json%28%24jsonText%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cenvelope%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdataset%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAA%3E%7B%24json%3Fa%7D%3C%2FAA%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Car1%3E%7B%24json%3Farr%3F*%3Far1%7D%3C%2Far1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Car2%3E%7B%24json%3Farr%3F*%3Far2%7D%3C%2Far2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdataset%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fenvelope%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=&input-type=None).

If you really want to go the route of using both XPath 3.1 selection into the XDM maps/arrays as well as to work with the `json-to-xml` conversion then I think you want to change `<xsl:apply-templates select="$json => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json'} ) => json-to-xml()"/>` to e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="($json => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json'} ) => json-to-xml())//fn:array[@key = 'arr']"/>` or to declare `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>`.

Comment: this is not working as arr is an array. 

Exception :
 XPTY0004  An item on the LHS of the '?' operator ($json ? "arr") is an array, but a value
  on the RHS of the operator ([map{(:size 6:)}, ]) is not an integer
at template init on line 9 column 31 of test_arr.xslt:

Comment: @UjjwalKumarVivek, I added a link to an online sample that does work for me.

Comment: Also note that about ten minutes before your first comment I had changed the code to use e.g. `$json?arr?*?ar1`, I think the error you get is because you used the initially posted `$json?arr?ar1` which was my mistake.